# IntelliJ IDEA - GUI Designer - Cannot load Preview form

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jform-designer

I have a real trubble for a beginner)

When I try to see Preview while working in GUIform (even when class is empty), I see an error:

```
Cannot preview form '.../SimpleG.form'
Reason: cannot load /com/intellij/uiDesigner/FormPreviewFrame.class
```

// I have installed plugin JFormDesigner and didn't find how/where to install UIDesigner plugin.

Project SDK 1.8;

Project language level SDK default (8)

Comment: Please ask you question in english as this is a site requirement. Many more people will be able to help you solve your problem.

Comment: yeap, Thomas, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [IDEA-237293](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237293). Will be fixed in the next release (around May 26th).

[image]

Comment: Oh no! Do you know whether it is possible to downgrade the current version of Intellij?

Comment: Yes, you can manage your IDEA and other JB product installations via the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) app.